# What are the pros and cons in sending a research paper to well-known author, before publishing?

Tags: publications, research-process

Currently I am reading a research paper of a well-known author published in 2011. I did a slight modification in his method and the new method is very efficient.

Is it reasonable to send that paper first to the author before sending it to any journal?

Comment: Do you mean: sending a draft or sending a published (or: submitted, posted on arXiv) paper?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've worked on a few method development projects and I'm of the opinion that it is a good idea particularly if the author is well-known and well-liked (if they are a dick or you don't like them, that's a different story).

The obvious reason why is because when they happened to see your paper going out for review which claims a "massive improvement" over previous methods, they aren't going to get upset at you and pull strings to make your life miserable. Furthermore, they might have insight whether or not the new method is useful or merely enhancing a particular error which makes it look good.

The only instance where sharing the paper might be a bad idea is if they happened to be working on a similar improvement. Receiving the paper may motivate them to scoop you.

Comment: Thank you very much. Author is still working in that area. I am just worried he may take my idea and publish in another form saying that my work is not that much appropriate.

Comment: @srijan Some areas have preprint archives (math, physics, and theoretical CS use arXiv.org).  These are public websites, where you can submit your paper before you submit it to a journal.  Anyone who wants can download and read your paper.  When you submit your paper here, it gets a time stamp, which can help with priority disputes.

Comment: @ Dear sir, my area is mathematics. Can you please tell me how can these websites help?

Comment: arXiv.org also accepts publications in mathematics. Check it out!

Comment: Oh, if you're in math, you're fine since arXiv is very forgiving. If you're in stem cells, or miRNAs, that's a different story. Actually in those cases you should never send anything to anyone. Even your significant other.

Comment: @bobthejoe I have got few papers related to my field. I want to know what they actually do? What about copyright? Do they improve your paper and send us back? How much time it takes for review? Sorry for this much question. Thanks a lot

Comment: @srijan: Maybe this should be a new question, but just look at the site.  You send them a preprint and they post it; that's all.  There is a short verification process to check that you are actually a mathematician and not a crackpot; otherwise there is no review at all.

Comment: _Receiving the paper may motivate them to scoop you._ — Or it may motivate them to make you a coauthor!  (See "well-known and well-liked".)

Comment: I think JeffE's comment essentially summarizes the dilemma. If the person is a helpful person, they are going to be a helpful person. If the person scoops people, chances are you'll be scooped. Asking the senior professors for their assessment is probably the way to go.

Comment: @bobthejoe Problem with me is that I don't know him personally. Neither my guide know him. Thanks for replying.

Comment: @JeffE I don't know him personally. In that case what would be the best option?

Comment: @srijan: Ask someone who knows him personally.  If that's not possible, ask someone _who knows someone_ who knows him personally.  But even if you can't get a sense of their personality, you can protect against scooping by _first_ posting your paper to the ArXiv and _then_ drawing attention to your ArXiv preprint.

Comment: @JeffE k sir , i contacted with him and i get a positive response. Still do i need to go fro pre print from arxiv..?

Comment: I think that the preprint (depending on your field, math sounds like one of them) is just good practice. Sounds like you're in a great situation. The only question left is whether he gets a name on the paper or an acknowledgement.